# Monitoring PVC Usage with Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-pvc

I am using Prometheus 2.33 version.
The following query does not work.

> kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes

> kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes

The following query is used to monitor the DISK usage of the POD.

> container_fs_usage_bytes

> container_fs_limit_bytes

Is there a way to get the usage of PVC, Limit value?

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize two metrics to monitor your Persistent Volume Claims (PVCs), despite the name "volume" being used. The metrics are as follows:

- `kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes`: This metric indicates the total capacity of the volume.
- `kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes`: This metric represents the current usage of the volume.

To specify a particular PVC, you can employ the filter `persistentvolumeclaim="PVC_NAME"` and replace "PVC_NAME" with the actual name of your PVC.

For instance, you can calculate the usage percentage using the following query:

```
100.0 * kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{job="kubelet", namespace="btel", persistentvolumeclaim="storage-volume-cpro-server-1"} / kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes
```

This query provides the usage percentage for the PVC named "storage-volume-cpro-server-1" in the "btel" namespace, based on the kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes and kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes metrics.

Answer (score 1):

For PVC, Kubernetes exposes these metrics to Prometheus, you can use them to monitor a persistent volume's usage:

```yaml
kube_persistentvolume_capacity_bytes 
kube_persistentvolumeclaim_resource_requests_storage_bytes
```

**EDIT**:
These metrics are from [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) - a service that produces Prometheus format metrics based on the current state of the Kubernetes native resources. It is basically listening to Kubernetes API and gathering information about its resources and objects, in particular for PV - [PV metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/persistentvolume-metrics.md) and PVC - [PVC metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/persistentvolumeclaim-metrics.md). More information about the service is [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/13/kube-state-metrics-v-2-0/).

Comment: Is there a guide or document for "Kube_PersisitTVolumeclaim_Capacity_Bytes" I can not even search.

Comment: @[김태우](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9538647/%ea%b9%80%ed%83%9c%ec%9a%b0 "659 reputation") my apologies, I've misspelled the metrics' names. I've edited the answer, please check.